# Ionic - Windows 10 app . Window.open() not working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, windows-10, cordova-win10

I have an ionic 2 app from which I am building IOS/Android and windows 10. In some of the pages I use the function `window.open(file.MediaUrl, "_blank");` to open files in browser.

On IOS and Android, the function is working properly and opening the links from the browser, however on windows 10 app, it is opening a new app window(not browser) then crashing and closing the whole app.
Any idea why?

Comment: It it opening a blank app window then closing up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made it work by using this.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/